# Generate report in Sharepoint for counting files based on filename

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have the following folder-file structure created in Sharepoint:

```
Library -- Tech docs -- Team A -- A_01.doc, A_02.xls, A_03.doc etc.
                        Team B -- B_01.doc, B_02.doc
           Process docs -- Team A -- A_01.doc
                           Team B -- B_01.pdf
```

I want to generate a report, which shows data like:

```
     Tech docs      Process docs
A      3                1
B      1                1
```

Using this format, I can extend my report to a PivotTable, PieChart etc. Is there a direct way that Sharepoint (or SP Designer) can read the filenames and give back a consolidated count?

Answer (score 0):

Using Sharepoint Designer you would need to use a List View or a Data View and then manipulate the XSL to return the desired result. Even with a lot of XSL experience, this will not be a mean feat.

An alternative approach is to export a list view to Excel. By default, the Path will be included in the query result. You can use Excel formulas (dynamic) or the Text To Columns functionality (quick one-off) to splice the path into individual folders and then create a pivot table to do the aggregation.